# Why are pages generated into folders?

Tags: eleventy

I am wondering why after running 'build' my nunjucks pages (other than index.njk) are getting output into separate folders?  For example, if I have a file 'src/products.njk', it will be output to 'dist/products/index.html'.

For example

```
src
|-- index.njk
|-- products.njk
```

```
dist
|-- index.html
|-- products
           |-- index.html
```

If there is an advantage to this type of renaming could you explain it to me?

Can this be overriden so that the file remains in the same output folder as 'dist/products.html'?  Or is that an unwise thing to do?

Comment: I read that I can set the output filename by adding permalink tag to the front matter.  My question still remains that why is the default to output pages into an index.html file in a folder that has the same name as the page?  What is the reason for this?

Comment: Simpler urls? So instead of going to mysite.com/about.html, you can go to mysite.com/about.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is seen as modern best-practice to not make users go to `/products.html`, but let `/products` be sufficient.

This also allows for easier migrations to a different stack, as you are not tied into one filetype.

See what the W3c says about URL styling [here](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html), and also what the [Eleventy docs](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/permalinks/#cool-uris-dont-change) have to say for more info.